# WebClient not connecting on localhost

Tags: mysql, xamarin

I'm following Joe Rock's Xamarin tutorial on YouTube and I'm having a puzzling problem with WebClient. It won't access a php script running on localhost.
I've opened the firewall to port 3306, added internet permission to the app, tried localhost, 127.0.0.1, COMPUTERNAME, all with and without :3306. I've tried several different emulators as well as an Xperia running Android 5.1. The code I'm using is as follows. I've also tried client.UploadValues.

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/CreateContact.php");
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

        parameters.Add("Name", txtName.Text);
        parameters.Add("Number", txtNumber.Text);

        client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);

        client.UploadValuesCompleted += client_UploadValuesCompleted;
```

There is no problem with the name-value pairs in parameters. I've printed them with writeline.console. The app doesn't produce any errors until I try to read back the value returned by the PHP script, but the CreateContact.php page is not being reached because debug messages at its very start are not being sent. The script works fine when accessed directly in a web browser.

Any ideas anyone? Thanks!

Comment: localhost refers to either the device or the emulator that the app is running on.  You need to use the IP of the server, or a FQDN.  An easy way to test this is to verify that you can connect to the service url using the browser.  Be sure your server accepts remote connections, the firewall is disabled, etc.

Comment: I wonder if you could clarify your comment "connect to the service url using the browser." From what I understand, MySQL isn't a web service and the old MySQL web is now MySQLWorkbench. So I couldn't figure out how to check via that route.   In any event, I have created a new user with all privileges and all hosts. The user and host list now shows both "steve | %" and "steve | windowsdesktop" WindowsDesktop is the computername and should remedy the problem with localhost. The firewall is letting port 3306 but I'm not sure how to confirm that the server is accepting remote connections. Thanks

Comment: "http://localhost/CreateContact.php" is the service url - verify that you can connect to that from the browser on the device/emulator.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the further advice. I can connect to and run the php script from a browser in the emulator. But the problem is somewhere else. When I substitute an ordinary webpage in the WebClient call it does reach it. But when I try to use WebClient to access the php script it doesn't connect. Could there be some permission issue? I've checked Internet permission in Visual Studio. Could it be something else?

Comment: It turns out that the connection problems go away when I run Visual Studio as Administrator.